# Unable to play Vimeo or Dailymotion video in Android Webview

Tags: android, android-webview, vimeo

I am unable to play Vimeo or DailyMotion Video in android webview.I still get thumbnail and play button for video.But when I click on play button nothing happens and video does not play.However,I am able to play Youtube videos perfectly.Does Vimeo or Dailymotion videos require Adobe Flash Player plugin?I have also implemented WebChromeClient.
I am testing on Android 4.1 device.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally the videos are working fine using the below code implemented:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 8) {
            contetView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
        } else {
            contetView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
        }
```

Comment: This does not work anymore , do you have any other solutions?